# How to enumerate through an object's properties in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to get for Each to enumerate through an object's properties and show up unique results. For example I'm trying to iterate through all the messages in a server and only display those where the current user is a sender
. And while doing that I want, to pull up all the receivers, create a group for each and display every message that interacts with that receiver. However I can only get to the point where I am displaying all messages but if a receiver comes twice it will create two separate groups with the same receiver instead of one.

I've tried to enumerate through the properties, but I get an error saying that you cannot apply a for Each on an object's properties.

```
<% message.forEach(function(message){%>
 <% message.sender.id.forEach(function(message){ %>
    <% if(currentUser._id.equals(message.sender.id)) {%>
    <div>
      <p>Message sent to <%= message.receiver.username %></p>
        <ul>
          <li><%= message.text %></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
    <%}%>
<%});%>
```

I'm expecting a div with each receiver and its correspondence instead I get multiple groups(one group per message found with the same receiver

Answer (score 0):

I think you misplaced a bracket. Please try code below.

**suggested code**

```
   <% message.forEach(function(message){%>
     <% message.sender.id.forEach(function(message){ %>
       <% if(currentUser._id.equals(message.sender.id)) {%>
         <div>
           <p>Message sent to <%= message.receiver.username %></p>
             <ul>
               <li><%= message.text %></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
      <%};%> //I moved a bracket from this line to the next line
    <%})%>
 <%});%>
```